# Use HashMap for storing Orders of Customer in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm building a program that is about `Fruit` Shop and I have to save order list of customer , I use a `HashMap<String, arrayList <Fruit> >` string for customer name . Now ,if a customer have many orders , how can i save it in Hash Map  ? Thanks

Comment: Multimap perhaps, `Map<String, List<Orders>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an object-oriented language you should aim to create a class to encapsulate each important concept used by your application. You've described the need to keep a list of customer orders, so why not create a new class called `Order` which contains data about a single order. As a crude start it might look like this:

```
public class Order {
    private List<Fruit> basket;

    public void addFruitToOrder(Fruit fruit) {
        basket.add(fruit);
    }

    public List<Fruit> getBasket() {
        return basket;
    }
}
```

Now your map from customer name to order can simply be `Map<String, List<Order>>` and each customer can have as many orders associated with them as you need.

To add an order to a customer name which may or may not already be a key in your `Map` you can use the `computeIfAbsent` method:

```
mapFromNameToOrderList.computeIfAbsent(
        customerName, n -> new ArrayList<>(4)).
        add(latestOrder);
```

The method `computeIfAbsent` will return the existing `List<Order>` for the given customer name if such a list already exists; if no list already exists for the given customer name then it will create a new List using the lambda expression `n -> new ArrayList<>(4)`. This way you can call the method `add` without worrying about whether or not the list already exists.

Also, your `Order` class can modified to contain additional data which belongs to the specific order, such as the total price, a unique order serial number, and so on.

Giving a specific concept such as a specific order its own class should make your code easier to write, easier to read, and much easier to maintain.

Comment: I don't know anymore , but in my method Shopping , when a customer buy a Item , I add it in a temp Array list <Fruit> then , when customer choose order now , I will put it in Hash Map . But next time , with the same customer , the key has already existed , then I can't put it

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can use the `computeIfAbsent` method so that you can simply add a new order to your map whether or not an inner list has already been created for that customer name.